# Migrating Wunderlist to Trello

Tags: export, trello, wunderlist

Due to the imminent retirement of the task management application [Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com) after being acquired by Microsoft, I recently changed to [Trello](https://trello.com). Now I was wondering if anyone made any experiences about the best way to migrate data from Wunderlist to Trello.

You can [export Wunderlist's](https://6wunderkinder.desk.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2364564-how-can-i-backup-export-my-data-) lists and data in the account settings and it is possible to [import data to Trello](https://help.trello.com/article/751-importing-data-into-trello). Although the exported Wunderlist data is in the form of .txt and .html files and so far I did not find a way to import that to Trello.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found a Github Repository to [Migrate data from Wunderlist to Trello](https://github.com/gamecat69/wunderlist-to-trello) with Python code along with some instructions but I have not tried it myself. Providing the source code works, this might be helpful to those that are comfortable to use source code for the task.